# Mapping a 2-sheeted Riemann surface with 2 branch cuts to a Torus

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, branch-cuts

A 2-Sheeted Riemann surface, with 2 branch cuts has a genus 1. A ring torus also has a genus 1 (In fact, section 13.4 of John Terning's book, modern supersymmetry and dynamics and duality claims that by joining branch cuts on one sheet with branch cuts on other gives a torus. For example, look at page 5 of [this pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/Riemann.pdf).

My question is, is there a conformal mapping which maps 2-sheeted Riemann surface with 2 branch cuts to a torus? Is $y^2=x(x−1)(x−a)$ the "mapping" (here the branch points of the Riemann surface are at $0$, $1$, and infinity)?

Note: If there is any more information needed to make the question clear please let me know, I will try (I am not from a mathematical background).  As a physicist, I understand torus as a rectangle on a patch of complex plane with periodic boundary conditions (or a rectangle where the opposite sides are identified with each other.)

Also, does a torus have translational symmetry (In the sense that for example, any point z in the complex plane, is similar to $z + c$ where $c$ is some constant)?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you can form a conformal structure on the torus not just from a rectangle, but more generally from a parallelogram, with periodic boundary conditions. Furthermore, different choices of parallelograms *may* give two conformal structures on the torus which are not conformally equivalent.

For example, any two tori formed from two rectangles are conformally equivalent if and only if the length/width ratios of those rectangles are equal. And when you bring in parallelograms, there are still a lot more conformally inequivalent possibilities.

In fact there is an entire "moduli space" of conformal structures on the torus. For each value of $a$, the Riemann surface defined by the equation $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-a)$ is just one of those points.

So when you read a statement like you referred to, there are two things to keep in mind.

First, the statement can be understood from a purely topological perspective, namely that the Riemann surface in question is *homeomorphic* to the torus.

Second, the statement can be understood from a conformal perspective, namely that the Riemann surface in question represents one particular point on the conformal moduli space of the torus.

There is an whole subfield of conformal geometry called [Teichmuller theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_space), where one analyzes the moduli space of conformal structures on a given topological surface.